# Load an arbitrary .BSON file into Flux.jl which wasn't created using Flux

Tags: julia, onnx, flux.jl

Right now, I am trying to load an arbitrary .BSON model into Flux which looks like the following:

```
weights = ONNX.load_weights("weights.bson")
Dict{String, Any} with 521 entries:
  "Constant_123"  => fill(1.0)
  "Constant_3300" => fill(2.0)
  "Constant_2837" => fill(0)
  "Constant_2150" => fill(1.0)
  "Constant_3712" => fill(2.0)
  "Constant_1246" => fill(0.5)
  "Constant_2970" => fill(16)
  "Constant_3817" => fill(0.125)
  "Constant_1134" => fill(1.0)
  "Constant_2064" => fill(1)
  "Constant_3538" => fill(0.125)
  "Constant_3896" => fill(1.0)
  "Constant_397"  => fill(2)
  "Constant_148"  => fill(1)
  "Constant_3807" => fill(0)
  "Constant_47"   => fill(-1)
  "Constant_3215" => fill(2.0)
  "Constant_1378" => fill(2)
  "Constant_2551" => fill(1.0f-5)
  ⋮               => ⋮
```

Now that I have the weights, I am unsure how I can get that into a model. Normally you could follow the steps here: https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/saving/#Saving-and-Loading-Models but those don't seem to work since they assume you created your model with Flux which isn't the case here. I downloaded an ONNX model file and converted it to a BSON weights file.

Answer (score 1):

I use ONNXNaiveNASflux to convert a ONNX model to Flux. Here is an example for the VGG16 network, where the model is converted to a Metalhead model:

```
using Flux
using BSON
using Metalhead
import ONNXNaiveNASflux


# VGG16 from model                                                                                                                                                    
# https://github.com/onnx/models/tree/master/vision/classification/vgg                                                                                                
# direct link:                                                                                                                                                        
# https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/onnx/models/master/vision/classification/vgg/model/vgg16-7.tar.gz                                                         
fname_onnx = "vgg16.onnx"
fname_vgg = "vgg16-flux.bson"

vgg16 = ONNXNaiveNASflux.load(fname_onnx,(224, 224, 3, :Batch))

mvgg16 = Metalhead.VGG16(pretrain=false);

p = Flux.params(vgg16)
mp = Flux.params(mvgg16)

for i = 1:length(p);
    mp[i] .= p[i];
end

BSON.@save fname_vgg mvgg16
```

Note that you could also use the model `vgg16` directly without convertion.

For VGG, the images have to be loaded in to a range of [0, 1] and then normalized using mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406] and standard deviation = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225] as mentioned here:
https://pytorch.org/hub/pytorch_vision_vgg/

Here is an example where this model is applied to this [image](https://miro.medium.com/max/700/0*uC0r2wJEPqZj6kdg):

```
using Flux
using BSON
using Metalhead
using Augmentor
import FileIO
import Images

fname_vgg = "vgg16-flux.bson"

BSON.@load fname_vgg mvgg16

labels = readlines(download("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pytorch/hub/master/imagenet_classes.txt"))


imgurl = "https://miro.medium.com/max/700/0*uC0r2wJEPqZj6kdg"

imgname = download(imgurl)
img = FileIO.load(imgname) # color x height x width                                                                                                                   
data = Float32.(permutedims(Images.channelview(augment(img,Resize(224,224))),(3,2,1)));


function vggnormalize(data)
    cmean = reshape(Float32[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],(1,1,3,1))
    cstd = reshape(Float32[0.229, 0.224, 0.225],(1,1,3,1))
    return (data .- cmean) ./ cstd
end

data = data[:,:,:,1:1]

out = mvgg16(vggnormalize(data)) |> softmax;

for i in sortperm(out[:,1],rev = true)[1:5]
    @show labels[i],out[i]
end
```

which outputs the label and the corresponding probability:

```
(labels[i], out[i]) = ("golden retriever", 0.97731346f0)                                                                                                              
(labels[i], out[i]) = ("Labrador retriever", 0.011763259f0)                                                                                                           
(labels[i], out[i]) = ("Chesapeake Bay retriever", 0.0020537968f0)                                                                                                    
(labels[i], out[i]) = ("clumber", 0.0011090196f0)                                                                                                                     
(labels[i], out[i]) = ("flat-coated retriever", 0.0009839782f0)
```

This should be right:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Retriever

Or at least it is indeed a dog :-)